# UIButton does not scroll when adding to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have added a `UIButton`, and a `UILabel` to a `UIScrollView`.  I added two constraints to the button using Auto Layout, and none to the label.  I can see label moving on the screen, however I do not see the button moving.  I figure this has something to do with the Auto Layout constraints I added to the button.  I would like to see to the button scroll the same way I see the label scrolling around on the window / screen.

Below is how I set everything up:

```
_welcomeScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
_welcomeScroller.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_welcomeScroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
_welcomeScroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
_welcomeScroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
#ifdef DEBUG
[_welcomeScroller setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
#endif
[self.view addSubview:_welcomeScroller];
CGSize welcomeScrollerSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 2000);
[_welcomeScroller setContentSize:welcomeScrollerSize];

// add test label
_test = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 200, 200)];
[_test setText:@"TEST"];
[_test setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:44]];
[_test setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[_welcomeScroller addSubview:_test];

// add about btn to lower right
_welcomeAbout = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
[_welcomeAbout addTarget:self action:@selector(showAboutScreen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_welcomeAbout setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[_welcomeScroller addSubview:_welcomeAbout];

NSLayoutConstraint *pullToBottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_welcomeAbout attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_welcomeScroller.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-10.0];

NSLayoutConstraint *pullToRight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_welcomeAbout attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_welcomeScroller.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:-10];

[_welcomeScroller.superview addConstraints:@[pullToBottom, pullToRight]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Apple's technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html):

> In general, Auto Layout considers the top, left, bottom, and right
>   edges of a view to be the visible edges. That is, if you pin a view to
>   the left edge of its superview, you’re really pinning it to the
>   minimum x-value of the superview’s bounds. Changing the bounds origin
>   of the superview does not change the position of the view.
>
> The `UIScrollView` class scrolls its content by changing the origin of
>   its bounds. To make this work with Auto Layout, the top, left, bottom,
>   and right edges within a scroll view now mean the edges of its content
>   view.

The button isn't scrolling because constraints are set relative to the visible left edge of the scrollview.

Apple's solution suggests:

> Create a plain `UIView` content view for your scroll view that will be
>   the size you want your content to have. Make it a subview of the
>   scroll view but let it continue to translate the autoresizing mask
>   into constraints.

Inside this content view, you can use constraints as you would normally.